# Convertir decimal a Double

Tags: c#, double

Tengo un par de `inputs` los cuales "X" persona va a digitar un numero, estos pueden ser numeros enteros o decimales, si es decimal quiero soportar que la persona digite '.' o ',', la cuestion es que los convierta a `double`y los guarde en la base de datos:

```
string brutoConvert = bruto.Replace(",", ".");
string netoConvert = neto.Replace(",", ".");

//bruto conversion
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
clone.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(brutoConvert, clone);
dBruto = (double)d;

//precio conversion
var clone2 = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
clone2.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
clone2.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
decimal d2 = decimal.Parse(netoConvert, clone2);
dNeto= (double)d2;
```

En este ejemplo estoy recibiendo `"400,56"` como `bruto` y `"325.12"` como `neto`, según lo que hago es cambiar comas por puntos y despues hago una conversion a `double`, el problema esta es que al final me da:

```
dBruto=40056  
dNeto=32512
```

Ya intente cambiar Replace() al reves (punto por coma) y aveces le da la gana convertir y a veces no, que puedo emplear perfectamente para realizar la conversion si o si?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se da con NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, ya que, estas forzando los símbolos de decimales y separación, acá el tema deberia ser reemplazar puntos por comas.

```
            string bruto = "325.12";
            string neto = "400,56";

            string brutoConvert = bruto.Replace(".", ",");
            string netoConvert = neto.Replace(".", ",");

            //bruto conversion
            double bd = 0;
            double nb = 0;
            Double.TryParse(brutoConvert, out bd);

            Double.TryParse(netoConvert, out nb);

            Console.WriteLine("bruto convertiodo a doble : " + bd);
            Console.WriteLine("neto convertiodo a doble : " + nb);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Entonces, pasaria el string "400,56" a decimal y de ahi a double, sin pasar por clone y eso?

Comment: @Baker1562 agregue un ejemplo a mi respuesta para hacerlo más explicativo